# Finding index in an ArrayList

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, indexing

I have a CSV file that i stored as an arraylist in Java. Here's the code i ran

```
public class StockData {
private ArrayList<StockRecord> records;

public StockData() {
    records = new ArrayList<StockRecord>();
}

//reads the file from the folder
public void loadPriceData(String filepath) {
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(filepath));
        String line;
        StockRecord record;
        scanner.nextLine();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] results= line.split(",");
            double open = Double.parseDouble( results[1]);
            double high = Double.parseDouble( results[2]);
            double low = Double.parseDouble( results[3]);
            double close = Double.parseDouble( results[4]);
            double volume = Double.parseDouble( results[5]);
            double adjClose = Double.parseDouble( results[6]);
            //create the record
            record = new StockRecord(results[0], open, high, low, close, volume, adjClose);
            records.add(record);
        }
        scanner.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

}

The code works correctly however, i am having trouble with the next part of the project.
Data Example

1. Date        Open     High    Low     Close   Volume      Adj Close
2. 6/10/2011    128.85  128.93  127.26  127.6   238629400   126.97
3. 6/13/2011    127.89  128.24  127.05  127.7   207599800   127.07
4. 6/14/2011    128.87  129.77  128.82  129.32  160570400   128.68
5. 6/15/2011    128.24  129.3   126.68  127.02  300958000   126.39
6. 6/16/2011    127.06  127.97  126.32  127.3   308032800   126.67

I'm trying to print out the AdjClose price for a date range. say between 6/13/2011 and 06/15/2016. It seems like i would need to find the index of the date first and then print the price record.

How can i do this? I'm not sure where to start. Do i first need to save the date in the its own list/array and use that to find the index?

Thanks

Comment: You're storing dates as strings, which will make them hard to compare. You could instead store them as java.time.LocalDate.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to iterate through the list of StockRecord and compare each record's date to your specified range.  If it falls in the range you would print it.  This can be optimized if your list is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

To compare first date is preferable to use a data type [date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

If your array could scouring records and objects of type StockRecord comparing your date field you want to evaluate

```
for (StockRecord reg : records) {
        if(reg.date.after(historyDate) && reg.date.before(futureDate)) {
           System.out.println(reg.toString()); // print object
        }
    }
```

Comment: Incorrect information. You have mentioned the old legacy class java.util.Date, but then list methods for an entirely different class, java.time.LocalDate.

Comment: Mention the methods to compare dates after and before, where is wrong?

Comment: You are conflating `java.util.Date` with `java.time.LocalDate`, two totally different and unrelated classes, the first from Java 1 and the other from Java 8. The `java.util.Date` class offers `after`, `before`, `equals`, and `compareTo` for comparisons. You listed methods for the other class. But really this `java.util.Date` class should be entirely avoided, and so too its sibling class `java.util.Calendar`. Poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: is right, I know a valid option but perhaps not the best. thanks for the tip right away I research

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is really a duplicate of many others in Stack Overflow.

## `LocalDate`

Your example code does not actually show the date as part of your `StockRecord` class. But it should be a member of type [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). Search Stack Overflow for countless posts on how to parse your input string into a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

## `Comparator`

Define a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for your class, to extract the `LocalDate` for comparisons. The `LocalDate` class itself implements the [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#compareTo-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-) method, as well as [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-), [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-), and [`isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isEqual-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-).

## Benefit of sorting

If you will be doing this query often, then it makes sense to sort the `StockRecord` objects into a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html). Then you can be smart about searching, again discussed on many other posts in Stack Overflow.

## `SortedMap`

You could organize the `StockRecord` objects into a [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), mapping the `LocalDate` to a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) of the `StockRecord` objects sharing that particular date. Using a `SortedMap` rather than a mere [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) lets you do smarter searches for a date range, as mentioned above. Again, many posts on Stack Overflow about maps.

## Apache Commons CSV

By the way, [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) project makes easy work of reading and parsing a CSV data file.

## `BigDecimal`

Do *not* use `double` or [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) for currency amounts, or for any fractional number where accuracy matters. Those types are [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) types, built for speed but trading away accuracy. You will be introducing extraneous extra digits into the end of the decimal fraction.

Instead use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Yet again, many posts on Stack Overflow on this class.

## Integers

Do not use a fractional number like [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) for an integer number such as your `Volume` field. Doing so wastes memory, and creates confusion to anyone reading your code.

Use a 32-bit `integer` or [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) if your maximum value is two billion or less (2^31-1 = 2,147,483,647), otherwise a 64-bit `long` or [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html).